# Prove that there exists a subarray with sum equal to K or S-K where S is the sum of the entire array

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

Suppose you are given two numbers N and S. Such that 1 <= S < (2*n). 
Now I want to prove that there exists an ordered tuple of length N having positive integers. And the sum of these integers should be S.
 Also if we take any K such that 0 <= K <= S, then there will be a contiguous segment in this tuple such that the sum of the elements in this segment equals either K or S-K. 
For example if we have N = 4 and S = 7. Then one such vector can be [1,2,1,3], there are N=4 elements with sum S=7
Now if we can take any K, 0<=K<=7, then we can find a contigous segment in the above vector whose sum of elements is either K or 7-K,  (i.e S-K) Lets see for some K 
K = 0 , we can select the entire vector (sum of the entire vector is 0 or 7-0)
K = 1, we can select the first element only (sum is 1 or 7-1)
K = 2, we can select the second element only (sum is 2 or 7-2)
K = 3, we can select the last element only (sum is 3 or 7-3)
K = 4, we can select the first 3 elements only (sum is 4 or 7-4)
K = 5, we can select the second element only (sum is 2 or 7-2)
K = 6, we can select the first element only (sum is 1 or 7-1)
K = 7, we can select the entire vector (sum is 0 or 7-0)

How to prove it? I tried using induction but failed

Comment: If all numbers in the vector are even, and $K$ is odd...

Comment: That wont be possible. This is because the minimum positive even number is 2. This means the sum of elements would then be greater than or equal to 2*n. But this violates the very first condition in the first line itself, that sum<=2*N.

Comment: @user58697 check the above comment